# Sequence That increases and then decreases using Modular Arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find a simple formula for a periodic sequence like this:

$$ 0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0...$$

I've figured it out for the increasing part of the sequence by using a modulo operator:

$$ i\  mod \ 5 $$

In that way, I have the desired upper and lower bound and it's periodic. The above formula gives me a sequence:

$$0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3...$$

Which is close. What change do I have to make to $$ i\  mod\  5$$  in order for the sequence to decrease?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about $-i \pmod 5$?

Comment: That's a step closer, it then becomes 0,4,3,2,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $4-\mid (i\%8)-4 \mid$.  (Here $\%$ is the mod operator.)  I think this gives the sequence
$0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,...$

Comment: This is a very nice solution.